# Empty return in func with return value in golang

Tags: go

I was reading some code written in **`Golang`** on Github and found a very interesting piece of code. I simplified it to be clear.

```
func  Insert(docs ...interface{}) (err error) {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        err = fmt.Errorf("")
        if err.Error()!="EOF" {
            return
        }
    }
    return 
}
```

I'm very confused about empty return here... How it works? Does he return nil as error or breaks for loop? I understand that this question looks dummy, but I cannot find any info on this in go docs... Also, I don't understand how we can return err, which is, as I understood, declared somehow in return. Does (err error) means that we already have an error variable available in our `func` which is used as default return value if none specified? Why then we implicitly make return err at the end of `func`?

I'll be very gratefull for explanation.

Comment: See "Named return values" in the ["Tour of Go"](https://tour.golang.org/basics/7) and ["Effective Go"](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The function uses a "named" return value.

From [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements) on return statements:

> The expression list may be empty if the function's result type
>   specifies names for its result parameters. The result parameters act
>   as ordinary local variables and the function may assign values to them
>   as necessary. The "return" statement returns the values of these
>   variables.
>
> Regardless of how they are declared, all the result values are
>   initialized to the zero values for their type upon entry to the
>   function. A "return" statement that specifies results sets the result
>   parameters before any deferred functions are executed.

Using named returns allows you to save some code on manually allocating local variables, and can sometimes clean up messy if/else statements or long lists of return values.

```
func a()(x []string, err error){
    return
}
```

is really just shorthand for

```
func a() ([]string,error){
  var x []string
  var err error
  return x,err
}
```

Its a bit shorter, and I agree that it may be less obvious.

Named returns are sometimes needed, as it allows things like accessing them inside a deferred function, but the naked return is just syntactic sugar as far as I can tell, and is never strictly required.

One place I see it commonly is in error return cases in functions that have many return values.

```
if(err != nil){
   return
}
return a,b,c,nil
```

is easier than

```
if(err != nil){
   return nil,nil,nil,err
}
return a,b,c,nil
```

when you have to write it a bunch of times. And you don't have to modify those returns if you change the signature to have additional "real" return values.

Most places I am using them in the codebase I just searched, they definitely seem to be hiding other smells, like overly complex multi-purpose functions, too deep if/else nesting and stuff like that.

Comment: can you post some example in which this kind of declaration cleans up if's or something like them? For me, this language feature looks like a bad design (i came from c#)

Comment: I don't have a strong argument for using naked returns, and would usually default to explicit. But I edited in some more considerations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, now i fully understand the problem! :)

Answer (score 8):

Go's return values may be named. If so, they are treated as variables defined at the top of the function.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func split(sum int) (x, y int) {
    x = sum * 4 / 9
    y = sum - x
   return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(split(17))
}
```

https://tour.golang.org/basics/7

Answer (score 5):

When you have a named return value (`err` here):

```
func  Insert(docs ...interface{}) (err error) {
```

This creates a function-local variable by that name, and if you just call `return` with no parameters, it returns the local variable. So in this function,

```
return
```

Is the same as, and implies,

```
return err
```

This is detailed [in the tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/7) and [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements).

Comment: Okay, but why we use empty return in for and implicitly write return err in the end of func?

Comment: Absolutely no good reason. It would probably be better to keep them consistent.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy Some good answers to that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089726/why-should-return-parameters-be-named)